# How to use multiple search bars on one viewController to access different JSON data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a viewController with 3 different search bars on it and a button next to each search bar.  The three search bars are for different categories(ie Movies, TV Shows) and when you press the button next to it its suppose to find an item at random based on what was entered in the search field. I know how to access the JSON data individually if there is only one search bar in the view Controller through appending the data to an array, but not if there are multiple search bars on the same view Controller.   [image: Sample Code for Search and JSON]

Comment: Sorry I can´t give you the right answer, because its getting down voted... By some guy... So will have to go on searching, or ask the voter what his problem is :-)

Answer (score 1):

by far the best option would be to have independent delegate objects for each search bar.

The second option would be to save each of the three searchbar on it's own property, ad distinguish in the delegate methods like

```
if searchBar == self.moviesSearchBar {
    //
} else if searchBar == self.tvshowSearchBar{
    //
}
```

Another option would be reconsidering the UI and have only one searchBar and a segmented control to switch the search scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can you have multiple independent UISearchBarDelegates on the same viewController?

Comment: it doesn't have to be on the view controller. actually it is a bad habit that doesn't die out (also because apple's example codes don't emphasize it and are taken as blue prints for architecture). The single most important architecture principles are the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Implementing delegates and datasources violates several of them, most importantly the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Search for "iOS massive view controller" for more on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Use the tag property (an integer) to identify each one.

Long answer:

You can do this via 
1) the Interface Builder's View section. See pic. 
2) programmatically yourSearchBar.tag =

Then, use the UISearchBarDelegate's `func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)` searchBar argument to determine which search bar triggered the delegate call.

It's true that you should follow the SOLID principles, though, whenever possible.

[image: Tag under View section after clicking on a UISearchBar]